# Is it possible to create a ConfigurationElement from xml text?

Tags: c#, xml, configuration, configurationsection, configurationelement

We have a custom class that inherits from `ConfigurationElement` called `SignalConfigurationElement` and defines a bunch of properties using the `ConfigurationProperty` attribute.

The `SignalConfigurationElement` class is part of a much larger hierarchy of configuration elements and does not have a constructor. I'm able to retrieve the entire configuration through the `ConfigurationManager.GetSection()` call, providing the root element's name which is `SystemConfiguration`, which is defined in the `<configSections>` of the app.config file.

I don't have control over the custom configuration elements so I can't alter them to provide constructors. I also can't modify the app.config because it's used by a much larger application.

Is it possible to create instances or collections of `SignalConfigurationElement` given an XML string of `<signals>` entries? The class doesn't have a constructor so I'm assuming the `ConfigurationManager.GetSection` call used by our other applications to retrieve the *entire* configuration (not what I want) uses reflection to create its instances.

Code (Can't change any of this at all.):

**App.Config**

```
<configSections>
    <section name="SystemConfiguration" type="Fully.Qualified.Namespace.SystemConfiguration, SystemConfiguration"/>
</configSections>

<SystemConfiguration id="System1" name="System 1">
    <equipments>
      <clear />
      <add id="Equipment11" equipmentType="EQ">
        <signals>
          <clear />
          <add id="EQ11Signal1" signalId="EQ11Signal1" type="Version" />
          <add id="EQ11Signal2" signalId="EQ11Signal2" type="Status" />
          <add id="EQ11Signal3" signalId="EQ11Signal3" type="Status" />
        </signals>
      </add>
      <add id="Equipment21" equipmentType="EQ">
        <signals>
          <clear />
          <add id="EQ21Signal1" signalId="EQ21Signal1" type="Version" />
          <add id="EQ21Signal2" signalId="EQ21Signal2" type="Status" />
          <add id="EQ21Signal3" signalId="EQ21Signal3" type="Status" />
        </signals>
      </add>
     </equipments>
<!-- And a whole lot more. Somewhere in the avenue of 30,000 <signals> entries.-->
</SystemConfiguration>
```

**Classes:**

```
public class SystemConfigurationSection : ConfigurationSection
{
/// <summary>
/// Determines the XML tag that will contain this Configuration Section in an .config file.
/// </summary>
public const string SystemConfigurationSectionName = "SystemConfiguration";

/// <summary>
/// Instance factory method for an instance of the Configuration Section creation.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>
/// Instance of the System Configuration section created based on the .config file of the application.
/// </returns>
public static SystemConfigurationSection GetSystemConfigurationSection()
{
    SystemConfigurationSection result =
        (SystemConfigurationSection) ConfigurationManager.GetSection(SystemConfigurationSectionName);
    return result;
}

/// <summary>
/// Represents the XML attribute used to store ID of the System.
/// </summary>
[ConfigurationProperty(IdConfigurationElementName, IsRequired = true)]
public string Id
{
    get { return (string) this[IdConfigurationElementName]; }
    set { this[IdConfigurationElementName] = value; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Determines name of the XML attribute that will contain ID of the System.
/// </summary>
public const string IdConfigurationElementName = "id";

/// <summary>
/// Represents the XML attribute used to store Name of the System.
/// </summary>
[ConfigurationProperty(NameConfigurationElementName, IsRequired = true)]
public string Name
{
    get { return (string) this[NameConfigurationElementName]; }
    set { this[NameConfigurationElementName] = value; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Determines name of the XML attribute that will contain Name of the System.
/// </summary>
public const string NameConfigurationElementName = "name";

/// <summary>
/// Represents the XML attribute used to store Description of the System
/// </summary>
[ConfigurationProperty(DescriptionConfigurationElementName, IsRequired = false, DefaultValue = "")]
public string Description
{
    get { return (string) this[DescriptionConfigurationElementName]; }
    set { this[DescriptionConfigurationElementName] = value; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Determines name of the XML attribute that will contain Name of the System.
/// </summary>
public const string DescriptionConfigurationElementName = "description";

/// <summary>
/// Represents the collection of the System's Equipments as they are described in the .config file.
/// </summary>
[ConfigurationProperty(EquipmentsConfigurationElementCollectionName, IsDefaultCollection = false)]
[ConfigurationCollection(typeof (EquipmentConfigurationElementCollection), AddItemName = "add",
    ClearItemsName = "clear", RemoveItemName = "remove")]
public EquipmentConfigurationElementCollection Equipments
{
    get { return (EquipmentConfigurationElementCollection) base[EquipmentsConfigurationElementCollectionName]; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Determines name of the XML tag that will contain collection of the System's Equipments.
/// </summary>
public const string EquipmentsConfigurationElementCollectionName = "equipments";

}
```

```
/// <summary>
/// Extends the standard .Net ConfigurationElementCollection re-definind commectio manipulation members and making them strongly-typed.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TElementType">Type of the Configuration Elements that can be included into the collection.</typeparam>
public class ConfigurationElementCollectionBase<TElementType> : ConfigurationElementCollection, IEnumerable<TElementType>
where TElementType : ConfigurationElement, new()
{
/// <summary>
/// Makes the addition operation public.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="customElement">Configuration element to add to the collection.</param>
public virtual void Add(TElementType customElement)
{
    BaseAdd(customElement);
}

/// <summary>
/// Overrides the base implementation of the overloaded method masking an exception throwing.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="element">Configuration element to add.</param>
protected override void BaseAdd(ConfigurationElement element)
{
    BaseAdd(element, false);
}

/// <summary>
/// Overrides the base property hardcoding the returned value.
/// </summary>
public override ConfigurationElementCollectionType CollectionType
{
    get { return ConfigurationElementCollectionType.AddRemoveClearMap; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Overrides the base implementation of the instance factory method.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>A new instance of the Configuration Element type determined by the type parameter.</returns>
protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
{
    return new TElementType();
}

/// <summary>
/// Overrides the base implementation of the method determining the indexing algorithm used in the collection.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="element">The configuration element to get index of.</param>
/// <returns></returns>
protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
{
    return ((TElementType)element);
}

/// <summary>
/// Collection's element accessor by index property.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="index">Index of the desired element in the collection.</param>
/// <returns>The requested collection element if exists.</returns>
public TElementType this[int index]
{
    get { return (TElementType)BaseGet(index); }
    set
    {
        if (BaseGet(index) != null)
        {
            BaseRemoveAt(index);
        }
        BaseAdd(index, value);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Overrides the collection's element accessor by key property.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="id">Key of the desired collection element.</param>
/// <returns>The requested collection element if exists</returns>
public new TElementType this[string id]
{
    get { return (TElementType)BaseGet(id); }
}

/// <summary>
/// Implements a standard collection method looking for an element in the collection and returning the element's index if found.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="element">The element to look for.</param>
/// <returns>Index of the element in the collection if exists.</returns>
public int GetIndexOf(TElementType element)
{
    return BaseIndexOf(element);
}

/// <summary>
/// Implements a standard collection method removing an element from the collection.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="url">The element to be removed from the collection.</param>
public void Remove(TElementType url)
{
    if (BaseIndexOf(url) >= 0)
        BaseRemove(url);
}

/// <summary>
/// Implements the standard collection member removing an element from the collection by the element's index.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="index">Index of the element to be removed from the collection.</param>
public void RemoveAt(int index)
{
    BaseRemoveAt(index);
}

/// <summary>
/// Implements a standard collection method removing an element by the element's key.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="id">Key of the element to be removed from the collection.</param>
public void Remove(string id)
{
    BaseRemove(id);
}

/// <summary>
/// Implements the standard collection method that clears the collection.
/// </summary>
public void Clear()
{
    BaseClear();
}


public new IEnumerator<TElementType> GetEnumerator()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
    {
        yield return this[i];
    }
}
```

```
public class EquipmentConfigurationElement : ConfigurationElement
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Represents the collection of the Equipment Unit's Signals as they are described in the .config file.
    /// </summary>
    [ConfigurationProperty(signalsConfigurationElementCollectionName, IsDefaultCollection = false)]
    [ConfigurationCollection(typeof(SignalConfigurationElementCollection), AddItemName = "add", ClearItemsName = "clear", RemoveItemName = "remove")]
    public SignalConfigurationElementCollection Signals
    {
        get
        {
            return (SignalConfigurationElementCollection)base[signalsConfigurationElementCollectionName];
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Determines name of the XML tag that will contain collection of the Equipment Unit's Signals.
    /// </summary>
    private const string signalsConfigurationElementCollectionName = "signals";

}
```

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents a type-safe collection of Equipment Unit Configuration Elements.
/// </summary>
public class EquipmentConfigurationElementCollection : ConfigurationElementCollectionBase<EquipmentConfigurationElement>
{
}
```

```
/// <summary>
/// Represensts a Signal's configuration element
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// As the class is derived from ConfigurationElementBase, a Signal's configuration element will expect "is", "name", and "description" XML attributes defined in the configuration file.
/// </remarks>
public sealed class SignalConfigurationElement : ConfigurationElement
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Represents an XML attribute used to determine type of the Signal.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// The attribute is expected to have a string value which is equal to one of SignalType enumeration member names: "Status" or "Command".
    /// </remarks>
    [ConfigurationProperty(typeConfigurationElementName, IsRequired = false, DefaultValue = "status")]
    public string Type
    {
        get { return (string) this[typeConfigurationElementName]; }
        set { this[typeConfigurationElementName] = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Determines name of the XML attribute that will contain type of the Signal.
    /// </summary>
    private const string typeConfigurationElementName = "type";
}
```

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents a type-safe collection of Signal Configuration Elements.
/// </summary>
public class SignalConfigurationElementCollection : ConfigurationElementCollectionBase<SignalConfigurationElement>
{
}
```

Comment: I've added code. Can't change the code in any way.

Answer (score 3):

This is possible through the dark arts of reflection.  Given the XML shown in your question, you can do this:

```
    var configXml = GetAppConfigXml(); // Returns the XML shown in your question.

    var config = (SystemConfigurationSection)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(SystemConfigurationSection), true);

    using (var sr = new StringReader(configXml))
    using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(sr))
    {
        if (xmlReader.ReadToDescendant("SystemConfiguration"))
            using (var subReader = xmlReader.ReadSubtree())
            {
                var dynMethod = config.GetType().GetMethod("DeserializeSection", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public, null, new[] { typeof(XmlReader) }, null);
                dynMethod.Invoke(config, new object[] { subReader });
            }
    }
    Debug.Assert(config.Equipments.Count == 2); // No assert
```

Reference: [source for `ConfigurationSection.DeserializeSection`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Configuration/System/Configuration/ConfigurationSection.cs,3bad2f78f1417912,references).

Incidentally, the configuration classes attached to your question don't match the XML.  Some properties are missing, and the properties that correspond to attributes in the XML must have [`IsKey = true`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationproperty.iskey%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  If the XML doesn't match the configuration classes, `DeserializeSection` will throw an exception.